# MySql Select data is many to many Relationship in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, random, relationship

- ENTRY (Table)

  ```
  ent_seq  entry
  100010      1
  100020      2
  100030      3
  100040      4
  ```
- K_ELE (Table)

  ```
  KID  entry   keb 
  1        1   食べる
  2        2   日本
  3        3   先生
  ```
- R_ELE (Table)

  ```
  RID  entry   reb 
  1        1   たべる
  2        2   にほん
  3        2   にっぽん
  4        3   せんせい
  5        4   ビール
  ```
- SENSE (Table)

  ```
  SID  entry
  1        1
  2        2
  3        3
  4        4
  ```
- GLOSS_ENG(SENSE Table's Child table)

  ```
  GID SID  mean 
  1     1  eat
  2     2  Japan
  3     2  Japanese
  4     3  theacher
  5     4  beer
  ```
- UPDATE (SENSE Table's Child table)

  ```
   UPID   SID    up_date 
    1     1    2012.12.12 17:31
    2     2    2012.12.12 17:31
    3     2    2012.12.12 17:31
    4     3    2012.12.12 17:31
    5     4    2012.12.12 17:31
  ```

**I like show this table.**

```
   ent_seq  keb     reb            mean             update

   100010   食べる   たべる           eat             2012.12.12 17:31
   100020   日本    にほん; にっぽん   Japan; Japanese 2012.12.12 17:31
   100030   先生    せんせい          theacher        2012.12.12 17:31
   100040           ビール   beer                    2012.12.12 17:31
```

**This database is very big 195000 rows PLEASE HELP ME!!!**

**MY SIMPLE CODE KKK**

```
 <?php include('con_db.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entry");
$number=mysql_num_rows($query);
for ($count=1; $count<= 20 ; $count++)
{ $entry = RAND(1,$number);

$query1 = "SELECT   
        entry.ent_seq, k_ele.keb, r_ele.reb, s_gloss_eng.gloss
        FROM entry, k_ele, r_ele, sense, s_gloss_eng
        WHERE entry.entry_pkey = $entry
        AND   sense.sense_pkey = s_gloss_eng.sense_pkey
        AND   entry.entry_pkey = sense.entry_pkey
        AND   entry.entry_pkey = r_ele.entry_pkey
        AND   entry.entry_pkey = k_ele.entry_pkey
        ORDER BY entry.ent_seq
        ";
$view2 = mysql_query($query1);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($view2);

    $ent_seq=$row['ent_seq'];
    $keb=$row['keb'];
    $reb=$row['reb'];
    $mean_eng=$row['mean'];
    $update=$row['update'];
?>

      <table width="614" border="1">
   <tr>
     <td>ent_seq</td>
     <td>keb</td>
     <td>reb </td>
     <td>mean</td>
     <td>update</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>$ent_seq</td>
     <td>$keb</td>
     <td>$reb</td>
     <td>$mean_eng</td>
     <td>$update</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do your tables have keys on all of those columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL database select many to many relationship in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824282/mysql-database-select-many-to-many-relationship-in-php)

Comment: i dont now first time this code writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  e.ent_seq,
  e.entry,
  ke.keb,
  re.reb,
  s.mean,
  s.up_date
FROM entry e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT entry, GROUP_CONCAT(keb) keb FROM k_ele GROUP BY entry) ke
  ON ke.entry = e.entry
LEFT JOIN (SELECT entry, GROUP_CONCAT(reb) reb FROM r_ele GROUP BY entry) re
  ON re.entry = e.entry
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT s.entry, mean, up_date FROM sense s
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT sid, GROUP_CONCAT(mean) mean FROM gloss_eng
               GROUP BY sid
              ) ge
      ON ge.sid = s.sid
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT sid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT up_date) up_date FROM `update`
               GROUP BY sid
              ) u
      ON u.sid = s.sid
  GROUP BY s.sid
  ) s
  ON s.entry = e.entry
```

Comment: SELECT e.ent_seq, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kei.keb SEPARATOR'; ')AS kebs, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rei.reb SEPARATOR '; ') AS rebs,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sei.mean SEPARATOR '; ') AS means
   
FROM entry e
  
    LEFT JOIN k_ele kei ON e.entry = kei.entry
    LEFT JOIN r_ele rei ON e.entry = rei.entry
    LEFT JOIN sense se ON e.entry = se.entry 
    LEFT JOIN s_gloss_eng sei ON se.SID = sei.SID
  
WHERE e.ent_seq IN (SELECT jt5.jlpt5_seq FROM jlptn5 jt5
          WHERE jt5.jlpt5_null = 0
          ORDER BY RAND())
  AND 
GROUP BY e.entry 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.ent_seq, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kei.keb SEPARATOR'; ')AS kebs, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rei.reb SEPARATOR '; ') AS rebs,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sei.mean SEPARATOR '; ') AS means

FROM entry e

LEFT JOIN k_ele kei ON e.entry = kei.entry
LEFT JOIN r_ele rei ON e.entry = rei.entry
LEFT JOIN sense se ON e.entry = se.entry 
LEFT JOIN s_gloss_eng sei ON se.SID = sei.SID

WHERE e.ent_seq IN (SELECT jt5.jlpt5_seq FROM jlptn5 jt5
                   WHERE jt5.jlpt5_null = 0
                   ORDER BY RAND())
GROUP BY e.entry    
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```